# How to create a JSON String from a list of objects and a JSON schema?

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, jsonschema

I have a list of objects which needs to be converted to JSON. I also have a JSON schema corresponding to which the objects should be placed in the JSON to be created. How can I achieve this? I cannot seem to find any references on the internet. Is this possible? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Java technology that that uses a json schema to influence serialization that I am aware of. If you use a library such as Jackson to serialize, it's up to you to use the available customization mechanisms to make any changes to the defaults needed to conform to the schema.

Answer (score 0):

If it's JavaScript, you can do it using Ajv and [custom keywords](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#defining-custom-keywords) that would generate the object you need as a side-effect of validation process.
Most likely you would have to define template that will be validated and the data that needs to be embedded in this template will be passed as a context into validation function:

```
var validate = ajv.compile(schema);
var context = { data: { /* ... */ } };
validate.call(context, template);
console.log(template); // template with inserted data
```